# Realizing a 3D-plot with Python from data stored in 3 matrices

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

Let M and N be to integers. One is given one vector s of size (M,1), one vector p of size (N,1) and one matrix u0 of size (M,N).

Assume one wants to 3D-plot (s,p) as the grid and u0 as the function to plot (the z axis). When one writes:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(s, p, u0, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                   linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

the terminal displays the following error message:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Yet, sizes do match! Is there a way 3D-plotting u0 over the grid (s,p) without using the arange function for the grid (*cf* the too much recurrent example at https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#d-plots-in-3d)?

**EDIT:** Here a MCVE. The original problem is exactly the one encountered with the following example.

```
import math
from math import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from pylab import plot, axis, savefig, show, title, meshgrid, cm, imshow, contour, clabel, colorbar
from numpy import exp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#

M = 10
N = 20

h = 1/float(M)
l = 1/float(N)

#

s = np.zeros((M + 1, 1))
p = np.zeros((N + 1, 1))

for j in range(0, M + 1):
    s[j] = 0.0 + 5.0*j*h
for k in range(0, N + 1):
    p[k] = 0.0 + 20.0*k*l

#

u0 = np.zeros((M + 1, N + 1))

for j in range(0, M):
    for k in range(0, N):
        u0[j, k] = exp(-(s[j] + p[k] - 10)**2)

#

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(p, s, u0, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                   linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: S and p should be mxn as well. For ech x and y point you have a z point

Comment: @Lucas Added, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Bazingaa What you're saying is interesting. Here what I've thought: the x-axis is given by a vector s with M entries, the y-axis by a vector p with N entries, the grid is built by the pair (s, p), and on the z-axis, the point of the graph of u0 above (s[j], p[k]) is given by u0[j, k]. Could you indicate me where I am wrong? You say that s and p are also matrices; what are their entries then?

Comment: I think you got the shapes exchanged. `p.shape` is (21, 1), try wit p.T

Comment: What I am saying is that for each X value you have N Y-values and for each Y value you have M X-values. Therefore you have total MxN X data points and MxN y points and for each of this MxN X-Y combinations, you have a corresponding Z values. What you need is to create a meshgrid of your X and Y points.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Comment: @Lucas Bazingaa's answer solved the problem, and you're right indeed, I needed to transpose my vectors (plus creating a meshgrid). Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am not sure if the output is the correct plot but here is the solution. Add the following line before `u0 = np.zeros((M + 1, N + 1))`

```
sv, pv = np.meshgrid(s, p) # creating a meshgrid of MxN points
```

and replace your plotting command by

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(sv, pv, u0.T, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
               linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: It worked on my original problem, so your answer is good. Nice job ! Thank you !